# Union dataframes in some way that updates rows with same row.name

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I want to do a union of two dataframes, that share some rows with same rowName. For those rows with common rowNames, I would like to take into account the second dataframe values, and not the first one's. For example :

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2), col2 = c(2,4), row.names = c("row_1", "row_2"))
df1
#       col1 col2
# row_1    1    2
# row_2    2    4

df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(3,6), col2 = c(10,99), row.names = c("row_3", "row_2"))
df2
#       col1 col2
# row_3    3    6
# row_2    10  99
```

The result I would like to obtain would then be :

```
someSpecificRBind(df1,df2, takeIntoAccount=df2)
#       col1 col2
# row_1    1    2
# row_2    10  99
# row_3    3    6
```

The function rbind doesn't do the job, actually it updates rowNames for common ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We get the index of `duplicated` elements and use that to `filter`

```
rbind(df2, df1)[!duplicated(c(row.names(df2), row.names(df1))),]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would conceptualize this as only adding to `df2` the rows in `df1` that aren't already there:

```
rbind(df2, df1[setdiff(rownames(df1), rownames(df2)), ])
```

Comment: Great, it does the job too